# Cannot get WMI connection to work in powershell

Tags: powershell, namespaces, wmi

I am trying to establish a wmi connection to a remote pc. I am currently in a domain, with strict policies.

So far I have granted myself explicit access to WMI in the DCOM settings. I have updated firewall settings to allow WMI. I have also changed the CIMOM AllowAnonymousCallback in Regedit. I think I am getting stuck on the namespace. I found the namespace for WMI but still get access denied.

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate -ComputerName "name" -Namespace root/...
```

I have tried taking certain pieces out, leaving others in etc. I just cant seem to get the connection. I keep getting access denied.

```
gwmi : Access denied 
At line:1 char:1
+ gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonati ...
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I needed to give myself permission in the WMI namespace. After doing that it worked.